# Editing the first line of a .gz file

Tags: unix

I have files

1. psmcHard_0.msOut.gz
2. psmcHard_0.msOut.gz
3. psmcHard_10.msOut.g

The first lines of each of these files are:

> compute 208 2000

I want to change it to:

> compute 208 3000

I tried doing nano `psmcHard_0.msOut.gz` but it didn't help. How can I do it?

Comment: Have you looked at `sed`?

Comment: yes but I don't know how can I use it since my files are .gz format

Comment: If they are .gz files this implies they are archives. You want to perhaps extract those archives and edit the extracted files (using `nano`?). Have a look at https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/howto-compress-expand-gz-files/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can handle this problem with that snippet of code below. After you write this code in a file (i will refer this file with 'script'), give it executable with `chmod +x script` and run it with `./script`.

```
#!/bin/bash

var="$2"
sed -i "1s/.*/$var/" "$1"
```

Example:

`./script "compute 208 3000" psmcHard_0.msOut.gz`

`./script {wanted text} {file name}`

Comment: Thank you Marceline. Your comment helped.